# Delaying macro expansion

Tags: c-preprocessor

Consider this code:

```
#define N_ 0
#define N_X 1
#define M(a) N_

M(arg)X;    //  #1 -- I'd like this to expand to N_X, and ultimately 1; but it's 0X instead
M(arg);     //  #2 -- this should and does expand to 0
```

The problem with #1 is that after expanding M(), the result contains N_, and *before* concatenating it with X, the preprocessor finds and expands it. 
Can I somehow delay this re-scanning of the result for further macros, such that the preprocessor finds N_X instead of N_?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First there is a different between `N_ X` and `N_X`. The first are two tokens. To form one token you have to use the token pasting operator `##`, but this operator inhibits macro expansion, so this:

```
M(a) ## X //Compiler error can't paste ')' and X
```

Causes a compile error, because its trying to paste `M(a)` and not `N_`. You can allow for macros to expand before pasting by using an extra level of macros(this is really commonly used macro):

```
#define PRIMITIVE_CAT(x, y) x ## y
#define CAT(x, y) PRIMITIVE_CAT(x, y)
```

However, in your case, this still won't work:

```
 CAT(M(a), X) //expands to 0
```

That is because, you are using object macros, rather than function macros. If you change it to function macros, it will work how you want:

```
#define N_() 0
#define N_X() 1
#define M(a) N_

CAT(M(arg), X)() // expands to 1
M(arg)()     //  expands to 0
```

Function macros are more powerful and you can delay the expansion of them. Here's how you can delay them for one scan:

```
#define EMPTY()
#define DEFER(x) x EMPTY()

N_() //Expands to 0
DEFER(N_)() //Expands N_ ()
```

Delaying macro expansion like this is one of the ways recursion can be implemented in the preprocessor.

Answer (score 1):

No. The preprocessor works line by line and performs no recursion or backtracking whatsoever. It reads a line, process a special `#` line or substitute something, and goes to the next line. This also means it doesn't make any substitutions before a `#define` nor after an `#undef`. You'll have to work around the issue.

Comment: and macros generally are evil

Comment: Drakosha: I would disagree. Learn them and their pitfalls and they can be a handy tool.

Comment: nightcracker: sure, u need to learn them, but you should try to avoid using them unless really it's the last option (and i upvoted your answer)

Comment: Oops, you're right. Even if I remove the definition for N_, the N_X resulting from the expansion of M() remains unexpanded.

Comment: Yeah recursive expansion would be a very very tricky thing for the compiler to do 0_0

Comment: Jesus Ramos: Not so much, but it would have many (unwanted) consequences.